# Convert pandas data frame to a dictionary with row elements as primary key and dict as value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm working in python3. 
I have a pandas data frame, and I would like to convert it to a dict.

The data frame looks like this:

```
    ID   year  country
0   123   2019  USA
1   456   2019  UK
2   789   2018  Sweden
```

I would like to end up with a dict, where the ID number is the primary key and the value is a dict. 'year' and 'country' should be the keys of the 'sub'-dicts.

The output should be like this:

```
{'123': {'year': 2019, 'country': 'USA'} , '456': {'year': 2019, 'country': 'UK'}, '789': {'year': 2018,  'country' : 'Sweden'}}
```

What is the fastest and best way to do this? It's a quite large dataframe. Is there any way to do it with `.to_dict`?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `df.set_index('ID').to_dict(orient='index')`

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my problem.

Comment: You're welcome :) happy coding